# Transition component not working for react headless ui

Tags: reactjs, headless-ui

I'm trying to use the react headless UI library for my dropdown menu. The docs say that I can add a Transition tag to make the dropdown animate, but for some reason the transition isn't applied. See the code below:

const DropDownMenu = () => {

```
    return (
        <Menu>
            <Menu.Button id='profile-button'>
                <Profile1 />
            </Menu.Button>
            <Transition
                enter="transition duration-1000 ease-out"
                enterFrom="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
                enterTo="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
                leave="transition duration-1000 ease-out"
                leaveFrom="transform scale-100 opacity-100"
                leaveTo="transform scale-95 opacity-0"
            >
                <Menu.Items className='dropdown profile-dropdown'>
                    <Menu.Item>
                        <button
                            className="dropdown-item"
                            onClick={() => setModal('account')}
                        >
                            <Profile2 className="dropdown-icon" />
                            Account
                        </button>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item>
                        <button
                            className="dropdown-item"
                            onClick={() => setModal('settings')}
                        >
                            <SettingsIcon className="dropdown-icon" />
                            Settings
                        </button>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item>
                        <button
                            className="dropdown-item"
                            onClick={() => setModal('help')}
                        >
                            <HelpIcon className="dropdown-icon" />
                            Help
                        </button>
                    </Menu.Item>
                </Menu.Items>
            </Transition>
        </Menu >
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Transition component need a special prop that it is "show". It gives a boolean value. So if you forgot adding it to this component it doesn't work.
So first you need a state to control toggling between 2 state  open and close. when you add this prop it will work correctly.
Please add this state to the component and set the state value as "show" prop in the Transition component

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It doesn't say anything about needing that in the docs, but I'll take your word for it that it worked for you. As for me, I ended up just creating my own reusable dropdown component wrapper that uses react spring. Works pretty nice, it relies on the open render prop.

Comment: Ok, Have you installed tailwind css???

Comment: I have not. I didn't recognize that as a requirement. But now I see.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the prop called "as" and use translate class utilities. Something like this:

```
<Transition
  as={Fragment}
  enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
  enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
  enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
  leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
  leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
  leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
>
{/* Other components */}
</Transition>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.